# Too many IF statements Excel / VBA

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I have added some sample data in this file to explain my problem a bit better. I have blended out the columns which have no relevance to the formula: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_lq0mYPF2ICiFgehQz_YkOa28JUyamG4G8ObV957onY/edit?usp=sharing

My initial file has one row per contract. I want to end up with one row per customer ID. I need to only keep the most recent contract, so the contract with the end date closest to Now(). If one customer ID has two contracts ending at the same time, I would like to keep the row with the higher monthly invoice amount.

I have been doing this with IF statements but there must be a more efficient way. At the moment the highest number of contracts a customer has with 3, but this will increase in the coming months and my if statement method will no longer be viable.

Here is my current formula.

```
Range("P2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(OR(Status=""in renewing process"",Status=""first contract still running""),""Not Eligable"",IF(Count_of_ID=1,""keep"",IF(Count_of_ID=2,(IF(AND(RC[-15]=R[1]C[-15],MIN(RC[-1],R[1]C[-1])=RC[-1]),""keep"",""delete"")),IF(Count_of_ID=3,IF(AND(RC[-15]=R[1]C[-15],RC[-15]=R[2]C[-15],MIN(RC[-1],R[1]C[-1],R[2]C[-1])=RC[-1]),""keep"",""delete"")))))"

Range("P3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(OR(Status=""in renewing process"",Status=""first contract still running""),""Not Eligable"",IF(Count_of_ID=1,""keep"",IF(Count_of_ID=2,(IF(AND(RC[-15]=R[1]C[-15],MIN(RC[-15],R[1]C[-15])=RC[-15]),""keep"",IF(Count_of_ID=2,(IF(AND(RC[-15]=R[-1]C[-15],MIN(RC[-15],R[-1]C[-15])=RC[-15]),""keep"",""delete"")))),IF(Count_of_ID=3,IF(AND(RC[-15]=R[1]C[-15],RC[-15]=R[2]C[" & _
        "-15],MIN(RC[-15],R[1]C[-15],R[2]C[-15])=RC[-15]),""keep"",IF(Count_of_ID=3,IF(AND(RC[-15]=R[1]C[-15],RC[-15]=R[-1]C[-15],MIN(RC[-15],R[1]C[-15],R[-1]C[-15])=RC[-15]),""keep"",""delete""))))))))" & _
        ""

Range("P4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(OR(Status=""in renewing process"",Status=""first contract still running""),""Not Eligable"",IF(Count_of_ID=1,""keep"",(IF(AND(Count_of_ID=2,RC[-15]=R[1]C[-15],MIN(RC[-1],R[1]C[-1])=RC[-1]),""keep"",IF(AND(Count_of_ID=2,RC[-15]=R[-1]C[-15],MIN(RC[-1],R[-1]C[-1])=RC[-1]),""keep"",IF(AND(Count_of_ID=3,RC[-15]=R[1]C[-15],RC[-15]=R[2]C[-15],MIN(RC[-1],R[1]C[-1],R[2]C" & _
        "[-1])=RC[-1]),""keep"",IF(AND(Count_of_ID=3,RC[-15]=R[1]C[-15],RC[-15]=R[-1]C[-15],MIN(RC[-1],R[1]C[-1],R[-1]C[-1])=RC[-1]),""keep"",IF(AND(Count_of_ID=3,RC[-15]=R[-1]C[-15],RC[-15]=R[-2]C[-15],MIN(RC[-1],R[-1]C[-1],R[-2]C[-1])=RC[-1]),""keep"",""delete""))))))))" & _
        ""
    Range("P4").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("P4:P" & Lastrow)
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Where does `Status` come from? Also, assume `Count_of_ID` is column `M`?

Comment: maybe just sort by End Date and Amount, then remove duplicates by Client ID? I can't check your file, but if you want to keep initial order of rows, add ordinal number column beforehand, then sort by it after removing duplicates.

Comment: In the 3rd, do you need all the IF's for Keep?  Can this be done with an OR?

Comment: HI @Tom, Status is a column that I hid. It says whether the contract was renewed, expired, is in the renewal process or if it is the customer's first contract. If it is the first contract. If the contract is in the renewal process or if it is the customer's first contract, the customer id is deemed not eligable and removed from the analysis

Comment: Hi @Nathan_Sav, Do you think including or would enable me to significantly decrease the size of the formula?

Comment: Noele, have you used Named formulas on Excel before? By creating a formula I can reduce the whole OR(Status... to a single word which clarifies the formula a lot

Comment: HI @AndyW :) I have used defined names of columns and used those in formulas (Status is also the name of a column). How are you able to reduce the whole OR(Status...) to a single word?

Answer (score 0):

I would use Named Formulae. They are not widely used in Excel but very powerful. As an example I reduced

```
=IF(OR(Status=""in renewing process"",Status=""first contract still running"")
```

to a single word returning true or false using a named formula. I have used relative addressing, excel handles this for you. The attached image should give you all the information you need to use it. I clicked on B2 and built the formula as normal, tested it then copied it, right clicked >DefineName, gave it a name and pasted the formula into 'refers to'.
To use it then just add the Name into the cell and Excel handles all the relative addressing stuff.

[image]